# Populating NAs and correcting data based on sequence within a sequence

Tags: r, data.table, na, updating

I have a data frame with two issues that I am trying to correct.  Here is a toy example.

```
        require(data.table)
        tempdt <- data.table(ID1=rep(1:6,each=2),ID2=rep(letters[1:2],6),name=c('john','john',NA,'mike','steve',NA,'bob',NA,NA,'henry','joe','frank'))

            ID1 ID2  name
         1:   1   a  john
         2:   1   b  john
         3:   2   a  <NA>
         4:   2   b  mike
         5:   3   a steve
         6:   3   b  <NA>
         7:   4   a   bob
         8:   4   b  <NA>
         9:   5   a  <NA>
        10:   5   b henry
        11:   6   a   joe
        12:   6   b frank
```

There are 2 sequential grouping variables (ID1 as the primary sequence and ID2 as the secondary sequence within ID1) and a name assignment.  Sometimes the name is missing and I need to fill this in based on what is assigned within that ID1 
and other times I might have 2 (or more) different names for the same ID1 but there should only be one. Whichever name comes first in the order of ID2 within ID1 should be the assigned name for all of that ID1

Ultimately the name field should read `c('john','john','mike','mike','steve','steve','bob','bob','henry','henry','joe','joe')`

I could approach this by ordering the data frame(table) based on the two sequential variables and then doing a for loop on ID1 and making the corrections but it seems like there should be a cleaner more efficient way
to sequence along ID1 and compare the sequence of ID2 within ID1 and make the corrections avoiding a loop.

Any thoughts?  I have it as a data table because I usually work with them but it isn't a necessity.

Will

Comment: Expected output shouldn't the last observation be frank?

Comment: No, it is what ever comes first in the sequence of ID2 within ID1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
tempdt %>% 
  group_by(ID1) %>% 
  arrange(ID1, ID2)
  mutate(name = first(na.omit(name)))

# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   ID1 [6]
     ID1 ID2   name 
   <int> <fct> <fct>
 1     1 a     john 
 2     1 b     john 
 3     2 a     mike 
 4     2 b     mike 
 5     3 a     steve
 6     3 b     steve
 7     4 a     bob  
 8     4 b     bob  
 9     5 a     henry
10     5 b     henry
11     6 a     joe  
12     6 b     joe
```

Comment: Neat (I took a detour it appears), add `tempdt[, name := first(na.omit(name[order(ID2)])), keyby = ID1]` for the `data.table` equivalent!

Comment: Awesome! Both the dplyer and the data.table solutions work. I've tried on a few tables of about 5K to 10K in length.  Thank you user2474226 and JDG.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
# Make a "Dictionary" of primary names per ID1 group
dict = tempdt[ , .(Name = first(name[!is.na(name)])), keyby = ID1] 

# Which ID1s correspond to NA names?
ID1_NA = tempdt[is.na(name), ID1]

# Draw correct names from the Dictionary
tempdt[is.na(name), name := dict[ID1_NA, Name]]
```

**Result**

```
> tempdt
    ID1 ID2  name
 1:   1   a  john
 2:   1   b  john
 3:   2   a  mike
 4:   2   b  mike
 5:   3   a steve
 6:   3   b steve
 7:   4   a   bob
 8:   4   b   bob
 9:   5   a henry
10:   5   b henry
11:   6   a   joe
12:   6   b frank
```

I do agree with sindri_baldur that there is some confusion concerning `name[12]`. Using your logic, it should be `joe`, right?

Would you want to also account for non-NA `name` entries that violate your "first name in ID1/2" sequence? If that is the case, you can merely add `tempdt[, name := first(name), keyby = ID1]` to the end of the operations above, as this will force `name[12]` to `joe`.